# find a special element of $Sp(2n,q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symplectic-linear-algebra

Please help me about this question:
I want to show that symplectic group $Sp(2n,q)$ has an element of order $q^n-1$.

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Let $(V,f)$ be $2n$ dimensional symplectic vector space on $|\mathbb F|=q$. There is a basis such that the matrix of $f$ is $\left[ \begin{array}{cr}  0 & I \\ -I & 0\end{array} \right]$. It is not hard to see that for every $A\in GL(n,\mathbb F)$, the matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cr}  A & 0 \\ 0 & (A^{-1})^t\end{array} \right]$ belongs to $Sp(2n,q)$.

Comment: how i can show order of this matrix is q^n-1

Comment: @Riana It is sufficient that you find a matrix of order $q^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Babgen You mean $q^n-1$, not $q^{n-1}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt yep, $q^n-1$